# pivot table does not correctly consolidate data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a number of customers, (A - D) and would like to consolidate the Sales into a pivot. But weirdly enough, it doesnt combine the data from the customers correctly.

My source table looks like this:

[image]

And the resulting "consolidated" pivot like this:

[image]

Why does it not consolidate Customer D into one row?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its most likely that there is an extra space in front of one of the Customer D values

`"Customer D"` vs `"Customer D "`